# Selective elimination from a list in R

Tags: r, list, function, lapply

I was wondering how I could eliminate the `x` elements *from the second variable on* (in this case, `x[[2]]` i.e.,  `0:90`) in list `x` whose corresponding `y` is `0`?

```
x = list(0:5, 0:90) # from the second variable on, in this list, eliminate elements whose 
                    # corresponding `y` is `0` ?

y = lapply(list(dbinom(x[[1]], 5, .9), dpois(x[[2]], 50)), round, digits = 4)
```

P.S. My goal is to possibly do this using `lapply` for any larger list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you could do

```
x[[2]][y[[2]] != 0]
```

to get your expected output.

However, as mentioned you have a larger list and want to do it for each one of them. In that case, we could use `mapply`

```
mapply(function(p, q) p[q != 0], x[2:length(x)], y[2:length(y)], SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

OR if we want to use `lapply` we could do

```
lapply(2:length(x), function(i) x[[i]][y[[i]] != 0])
```

If we want to keep the 1st element as it is we could do

```
c(list(x[[1]]), lapply(2:length(x), function(i) x[[i]][y[[i]] != 0]))
```

---

**EDIT**

To maintain the order we can rearrange the both `x` and `y` based on `smallest_max`

```
get_new_list <- function(x, y) {
   smallest_max <- which.min(sapply(x, max))
   new_x <- c(x[smallest_max], x[-smallest_max])
   new_y <- c(y[smallest_max], y[-smallest_max])
  c(new_x[1], lapply(2:length(new_x), function(i) new_x[[i]][new_y[[i]] != 0]))
}

x = list(0:5, 0:40)
y = lapply(list(dbinom(x[[1]], 5, .9), dpois(x[[2]], 50)), round, digits = 4)

get_new_list(x, y)
#[[1]]
#[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5

#[[2]]
#[1] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40

x = list(0:40, 0:5)
y = lapply(list(dpois(x[[1]], 50), dbinom(x[[2]], 5, .9)), round, digits = 4)

get_new_list(x, y)
#[[1]]
#[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5

#[[2]]
#[1] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
```

Comment: Ronak, is it possible for your `get_new_list` function to also output the corresponding `y` values for the `x` values?

Comment: @Reza yes, we can add them in a list. Replace last line in the function with `list(c(new_x[1], lapply(2:length(new_x), function(i) new_x[[i]][new_y[[i]] != 0])), 
       c(new_y[1], lapply(2:length(new_y), function(i) new_y[[i]][new_y[[i]] != 0])))
}` and it would return both `x` and `y` values.